# Selenium expected conditions - select element with multiple attributes

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select an element in Selenium using Python which looks like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2" an-attribute="attribute-value"></div>
```

and use it inside a wait on an expected condition like this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
 expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
  (By.XPATH, '//div[@an-attribute="attribute-value"][@class="class1 class2"]')))
```

This wait always results in a TimeoutException.

I've also tried the alternative XPath syntax:

```
'//div[@an-attribute="attribute-value" and @class="class1 class2"]'
```

I am able to get this element using the same XPath value in `find_element_by_xpath()`.
If I pause the test and inspect the browser web console, I can see that the div indeed has this attribute and classes. This is true for both Firefox and Chromium.

Is this a bug in Selenium or am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of a couple of facts as follows :

- As per the HTML you have shared the *webelement* doesn't looks to be *selectable* so you can't *select* perhaps you can invoke `click()` which would have been much more clear with the revealing of the exact `an-attribute` attribute.
- The [*WebDriverWait*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) which you have defined looks perfect but if moving forward if you are trying to invoke `click()` method then instead of [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause `presence_of_element_located` you should have used [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='class1 class2' and @an-attribute='attribute-value']"))).click()
  ```
- Still as `presence_of_element_located` is returning *TimeoutException* but in console you are able to locate it implies that the element is not within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css_rwd_viewport.asp). So you need to bring the *webelement* within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css_rwd_viewport.asp) first as follows :

  ```
  my_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1 class2' and @an-attribute='attribute-value']")
  self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", my_element)
  ```

Comment: Interesting! Maybe I used the wrong terminology with "select" - I meant "locate"; I don't want to click the element, just ensure that it's there. I did manage to get the wait condition to return without exception by scrolling to the element first - but this defeats the purpose of the wait condition! I want to ensure that the element is present before I continue; if I first scroll into view, then I get a transient error. I guess it was incorrect to say that I can reliably get the element with find_element_by_xpath(). Is there a way to wait until an element is present at all on the page?

Comment: Of-coarse each and every element are different and distinct on each webpage. Hence there can't be **any single element** present on all on the pages. On each and every page you have to find/locate the intended elements with different [_Locator Strategy_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

Comment: I wasn't talking about multiple pages; I just don't understand how to wait until a particular element is on a particular page. What is the point of presence_of_element_located if it does not wait until an element is *present* - and if it did, then why would I have to scroll to it before the wait? A scroll will fail if the element is still not present.